# Add parsed data to list

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, okhttp

So I have this function created to generate fake values for my list:

```
private fun generateFakeValues(): List<Torrent> {
    val values = mutableListOf<Torrent>()

    val torrent1 = Torrent()
    torrent1.name = "Big Buck Bunny"
    torrent1.downloadSpeed = 0.00
    torrent1.uploadSpeed = 0.00
    torrent1.downloaded = 59.23
    torrent1.length = 263.64

    values.add((torrent1))

    return values
}
```

And it works just fine. Now I added a Http request and wanted to parse the data but the items are not in the list:

```
private fun getTorrents(): List<Torrent> {
    var torrents = mutableListOf<Torrent>()
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("...")
        .build()

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            response.use {
                if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                    throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")
                }
                torrents = gson.fromJson(response.body!!.string(), mutableListOf<Torrent>()::class.java)
            }
        }
    })
    return torrents
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error you are getting?Also if you can post json you are trying to parse

Comment: No error. I just want to know how to return something form the onResponse function so that I can update my list

Answer (score 0):

Since network call happens on background thread. You have to publish data to UI thread like

`activity.runOnUiThread({/*add to adapter and notify data change to adapter*/})`

or

`view.post({/*add to adapter and notify data change to adapter*/})`